# i want replica of my database that is to be use by another database

Tags: mysql, database, replication

i have my database database1 for my company. 
i want to create another database for client's company.the client's company requirement is same as ours.so that i can use my database1 for creating their database.
   In database1 there is a tables which i want to use in client's company database. so please tell me how i can reduced the redundancy by using only database1 for my company and client's company too??? or do you think i want to make replica of database1??? if i have to make replica of database1,then how i can make it in mysql???
please suggest me how i can use one Database structure for other database.
i need your help.please tell me the right way of doing these.

Comment: you should make another same database for client.

Comment: Pls describe the situation in a more detailed manner including where do you plant to host the 2 databases, how future changes to database1 will affect the client database,  data privacy concerns (if any).

Answer (score 0):

If there is no separate server requirement from your client then you can do as per below-

I am assuming that some master tables will be always same for you as well your client as you mentioned that both have same kind of project, so create 3 databases on same server-

master_db : It will keep generic information tables, which will be used by you as well your client and should keep same information for both-

client_db : It will store tables those keep information for client like client's order can be different, need logs those will be different etc.

your_db : It will keep tables those you need only.

Note: Further it will depend how you are using db/tables in your code. Multiple DB setup will work for you or not. As per me it should not be any issue.